# Media query not working with max-width screen size (640px)

Tags: html, css, mobile, screen, media

I am making a responsive which changes layout if the screen size is 640px or smaller. I am told this is the size needed for most smartphones (E.G. iPhone). However, when I tested the website on 3 different smartphones (including a iPhone 5s) it still displayed the desktop site. It was only when I changed the max-width to 980px that it displayed the mobile variant on mobile devices.

Is this because the size of mobile devices is actually 980px, or is it because I have done the media query wrong (I'm new to them)? Do I need any code for the query in my HTML?

Here is my media query in my CSS:

```
@media handheld, screen and (max-width: 640px)
```

Here are my links in the Head of my HTML:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/normalize.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css">
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

======================UPDATE======================

Thanks for the answers. I was missing the meta tag and adding that fixed it (I'm new to media queries). It was working fine for a while but I added some things to both the CSS and the HTML and now it doesn't work again.

This time I will include a link to the uploaded website. Any other tips would also be appreciated as I am about 4 months new to web design.

http://ajhill.esy.es/

Comment: There's no much code to see here, but have you tried adding the `viewport` meta tag in your HTML? `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">`

Answer (score 0):

Try putting a jsfiddle of your code so that we can see where it is going wrong.

Besides try this once

```
@media handheld and (max-width: 640px), screen and (max-width: 640px) {

//your css here

}
```

instead of `@media handheld, screen and (max-width: 640px)`and see whether it makes any difference.